# Close pop up panel in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I wanted to close the pop up gridview in **asp panel ID="pnlPopup"** and inside the panel got the **gridview of ID="MultiSelectGridView1"**. I tried to close the pop up panel after put the selected value in textbox in parent page. But it return close all the window including parent page. Hope help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function setSearch(row) {
                var tbl = document.getElementById("<%=MultiSelectGridView1.ClientID%>");
                var txt = document.getElementById("<%=txtName.ClientID%>");
                txt.value = tbl.rows[row + 1].cells[1].innerText;
                window.close(<%=pnlPopup.ClientID%>);

            }
          </script>
```

Comment: A pop up and a window are different things. If you call [`Window.close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) (which has no parameters and will ignore the one you're giving it) an actual window (which is usually in fact a *browser tab*) will be closed - for so far the browser even allows JavaScript to do such a thing...

Comment: @Jeroen thanks for reply!! what suggestion for u to close the pop up?

Comment: If not mistaken the Pop Up modal should be use display none... It will be close

Comment: Alas, no suggestion yet, which is why I posted my info as a comment, not an answer. It's not convenient currently for me to use a test setup to check any answer I'd give, nor do I remember the gridview features around this. Have you checked out any documentation yet? Edit your question and let us know where you've searched and what other solutions you've tried. MSDN isn't the best, but surely it has *some* info on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use as below:

```
document.getElementById("<%= pnlPopup.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
```